# Restore quote in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, quote, php-7

I have canceled the current order like

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
$order->cancel()->save();
```

After that, create a new quote and assign the quote item using this link.

https://webkul.com/blog/programmatically-add-more-product-to-an-existing-quote-in-magento-2/

It's working fine. But when the ordered product has 1 qty, it returned the "product is out of stock" message.

How to resolve that.

How to restore the quote for payment failure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the `$cartItem->setQty($qty)` Function, May be this function is not getting 1 qty when you entered.

Please check once function parameter Value or set `$cartItem->setQty($qty = 1)` default value as one.

**Restore the quote for payment failure.**

in YourIcancelAction() Or failureAction();

Add below code:

```
if (\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::restoreQuote()->getLastRealOrderId()) {
    if ($lastQuoteId = \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::restoreQuote()->getLastQuoteId()) {
        $quote = \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item->load($lastQuoteId);
        $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mage::getSingleton is for Magento 1

Comment: use  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::restoreQuote()